# Regex in Python 3: match everything after a number or optional period but before an optional comma

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to return ingredients from recipes without any measurements or directions. Ingredients are lists and appear like the following:

```
['1  medium tomato, cut into 8 wedges',
 '4  c. torn mixed salad greens',
 '1/2  small red onion, sliced and separated into rings',
 '1/4  small cucumber, sliced',
 '1/4  c. sliced pitted ripe olives',
 '2  Tbsp. reduced-calorie Italian salad dressing',
 '2  Tbsp. lemon juice',
 '1  Tbsp. water',
 '1/2  tsp. dried mint, crushed',
 '1/4  c. crumbled Feta cheese or 2 Tbsp. crumbled Blue cheese']
```

I want to return the following list:

```
['medium tomato',
 'torn mixed salad greens',
 'small red onion',
 'small cucumber',
 'sliced pitted ripe olives',
 'reduced-calorie Italian salad dressing',
 'lemon juice',
 'water',
 'dried mint',
 'crumbled Blue cheese']
```

The closest pattern I've found is with:

```
pattern = '[\s\d\.]* ([^\,]+).*'
```

but in testing with:

```
for ing in ingredients:
    print(re.findall(pattern, ing))
```

the periods after each measurement abbreviation are returned as well, e.g.:

```
['c. torn mixed salad greens']
```

while

```
pattern = '(?<=\. )[^.]*$'
```

fails to capture instances with no periods, and captures the comma if both appear, i.e.:

```
[]
['torn mixed salad greens']
[]
[]
['sliced pitted ripe olives']
['reduced-calorie Italian salad dressing']
['lemon juice']
['water']
['dried mint, crushed']
['crumbled Blue cheese']
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
for ing in ingredients:
    print(re.search(r'[a-z][^.,]*(?![^,])(?i)', ing).group())
```

pattern details:

```
([a-z][^.,]*) # a substring that starts with a letter and that doesn't contain a period
                # or a comma
(?![^,]) # not followed by a character that is not a comma
         # (in other words, followed by a comma or the end of the string)
(?i)     # make the pattern case insensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pairing the number with the dot.

```
\s\d*\.?
```

should work to match the number correctly (with or without a dot)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to tweak your pattern a bit to get it to work --     
    [\d\w\s]*[\. ]+ (?:.* or [\d\w\s]*[\. ]+ )?([^\,]+).*
had to add in a passive group to deal with the case where there are two options, such as:
    '1/4  c. crumbled Feta cheese or 2 Tbsp. crumbled Blue cheese']

Answer (score 1):

## Description

I'd recommend the following regex to find and replace the substrings you not interested in. By having the unit of measurements spelled out this will also deal with unit of measures which are not abbreviated.

`\s*(?:(?:(?:[0-9]\s*)?[0-9]+\/)?[0-9]+\s*(?:(?:c\.|cups?|tsp\.|teaspoon|tbsp\.|tablespoon)\s*)?)|,.*|.*\bor\b`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Replace with:**  nothing

## Examples

**Live demo**

Showing how the this will match

https://regex101.com/r/qV5iR8/3

**Sample string**

Note the last line has the double ingredient separated by an `or`, according to the OP they'd like to eliminate the first ingredient.

```
1  medium tomato, cut into 8 wedges
4  c. torn mixed salad greens
1/2  small red onion, sliced and separated into rings
1/4  small cucumber, sliced
1 1/4  c. sliced pitted ripe olives
2  Tbsp. reduced-calorie Italian salad dressing
2  Tbsp. lemon juice
1  Tbsp. water
1/2  tsp. dried mint, crushed
1/4  c. crumbled Feta cheese or 2 Tbsp. crumbled Blue cheese
```

**After Replacement**

```
medium tomato
torn mixed salad greens
small red onion
small cucumber
sliced pitted ripe olives
reduced-calorie Italian salad dressing
lemon juice
water
dried mint
crumbled Blue cheese
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (0 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        c                        'c'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        cup                      'cup'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        s?                       's' (optional (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        tsp                      'tsp'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        teaspoon                 'teaspoon'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        tbsp                     'tbsp'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        tablespoon               'tablespoon'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  or                       'or'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The idea is interesting, but it isn't very handy to make an exhaustive list of possible terms like *teaspoon*, *tablespoon*... I will make it this way: https://regex101.com/r/zS7zR8/1

Comment: I thought so too but then the OP said the last line contained two ingredients but they only wanted the last one..., and if the measurement was spelled out like `tablespoon` instead of `tbsp.` in the last line, then you're proposed regex won't clean off the first ingredent

Comment: Yes it's a little strange.

Comment: Also it's really nice to cross paths with you again :)